# Howd do I toggle between 'previous searches' inside intellij, in other words, past 'find usages'?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse, there used to be a drop-down where i could click on 'past searches' so i could toggle back and forth between various search-history-results sets, is this possible in InteeliJ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click the Find view: there is an item named `Recent Find Usages` (You can also go to it using `CTRL+E` when you're in the Find view). Usually, `CTRL+E` is the contextual way to access history.

Please note that it doesn't save the results, but only the query. In other words, it executes the search again each time you use it.

Also note I'm using `IntelliJ 10.5.2`, not sure about older versions.

Comment: I was hoping that that wasn't the answer :(  My Recent Find Usages box is always blank.

Answer (score 18):

Whenever you search you have a check box of "Open in a new tab". If you do that then the results aren't overridden by a new search.

Answer (score 0):

In the most recent versions 2019 you either need to right click on search window to get past search results or use shortcut "alt+down" to pick from dropdown list.